# Failed to get current state: AuthKeyUnregisteredError('The key is not registered in the system')

Tags: telethon

I am using Telethon to connect to Telegram and pull down some messages to run analytics on. I wrote the original code in 2018 and it worked perfectly. It connected, read from the channel and allowed me to read messages as I expected. Recently I tried running the script again and it now keeps asking me for my phone number and authentication code despite the fact the session file has been created. In the past I only was asked for the phone number and authentication code once, then the session file was created and I did not have to repeat myself. Now I find myself doing it every time I run the program.

I should note that readChannel.session is created in my local directory and has following properties

```
$ file readChannel.session
readChannel.session: SQLite 3.x database, last written using SQLite version 3021000
```

I enabled logging and got the following

```
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotolayer:Assigned msg_id = 6755168064255177608 to InvokeWithLayerRequest (3601b10)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotolayer:Packed 1 message(s) in 68 bytes for sending
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Broken authorization key; resetting
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Closing current connection...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Awaiting for the send loop before reconnecting...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Awaiting for the receive loop before reconnecting...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Closing current connection...
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connecting to 149.154.167.92:443/TcpFull...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection attempt 1...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection success!
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:New auth_key attempt 1...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Starting send loop
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Starting receive loop
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection to 149.154.167.92:443/TcpFull complete!
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
INFO:telethon.client.updates:Asking for the current state after reconnect...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotolayer:Assigned msg_id = 6755168067804342024 to InvokeWithLayerRequest (3601b10)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotolayer:Assigned msg_id = 6755168067820286504 to GetStateRequest (3601f50)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotolayer:Packed 2 message(s) in 112 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling bad salt for message 6755168067844913236
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:2 message(s) will be resent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotolayer:Assigned msg_id = 6755168068088576072 to InvokeWithLayerRequest (3601b10)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotolayer:Assigned msg_id = 6755168068116633168 to GetStateRequest (3601f50)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotolayer:Packed 2 message(s) in 112 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotolayer:Assigned msg_id = 6755168068176325552 to MsgsAck (394c0f0)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotolayer:Packed 1 message(s) in 36 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling container
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling new session created
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling acknowledge for [6755168068088576072, 6755168068116633168]
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling RPC result for message 6755168068116633168
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
INFO:telethon.client.updates:Failed to get current state: AuthKeyUnregisteredError('The key is not registered in the system')
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling RPC result for message 6755168068088576072
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotolayer:Assigned msg_id = 6755168068470441572 to MsgsAck (3601ed0)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotolayer:Packed 1 message(s) in 36 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotolayer:Assigned msg_id = 6755168068486387960 to MsgsAck (3601e10)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotolayer:Assigned msg_id = 6755168068510330908 to GetStateRequest (3601d10)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotolayer:Packed 2 message(s) in 112 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling RPC result for message 6755168068510330908
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
Please enter your phone (or bot token):
```

It would appear the problem relates to INFO:telethon.client.updates:Failed to get current state: AuthKeyUnregisteredError('The key is not registered in the system')

Here is the code

```
api_id = xxx
api_hash = xxx
channel_name = xxx
client = TelegramClient('readChannel', api_id, api_hash)

# Connect to telegram
try:
    client.connect()
    client.start()
except:
    print ("Could not connect to telegram")

# Connect to channel and get posts
try:
    channel_entity=client.get_entity(channel_name)
    posts = client(GetHistoryRequest(
        peer=channel_entity,
        limit=1000000,
        offset_date=0,
        offset_id=0,
        max_id=0,
        min_id=0,
        add_offset=0,
        hash=0))
except:
    print ("Could not connect to channel ", channel_name)
```

Expected: I expected to be asked phone number and authentication code once and then it would read from the session file thereafter.

Actual: Now I find myself doing it every time I run the program (providing my phone number and authentication code).

Comment: make sure you're using the latest version there have been some changes lately

Comment: This sounds like a bug, and bugs should be reported in https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues.

Comment: I did not think it was a bug so logged it here. Will make sure on latest version (recheck) and if still a problem will log a bug.

Comment: @GerM Please conclude the chapter you have started, and help the information resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [sign_in](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/quick-references/client-reference.html?highlight=sign_in#auth) method

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

api_id = 'your_api_id'
api_hash = 'your_api_hash'
phone_number = 'your_phone_number'

# Create a TelegramClient instance
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

# Connect to the Telegram server
client.connect()

# Check if the user is not authorized
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone_number)
    client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter the code: '))
```